# Batch structure for training a ranking model with contrastive loss?

Tags: tensorflow, ranking, information-retrieval, loss-function

How do I choose my batch if I train a deep ranking model with a eg. contrastive loss where I have per query 1 positive document and 2 negative samples?

So, it is about ranking (loss) which applies to eg. the quora question pair data or any other question/answer pairs which I want to rank using a deep learning ranking model or just a Siamese network.

The data would look like this: https://github.com/NTMC-Community/MatchZoo/blob/master/matchzoo/datasets/toy/train.csv

Now, I assume that it is crucial how to build the batch, right? Since for every question all according pos and neg answers need to be contained inside a batch, right?

Answer (score 0):

Different strategies can be used to build the batches and the triplets or pairs. Usually, the batches are built randomnly, and then the hardest negative, or one of the hardest negatives in the batch is picked.

So yes, positive and negatives examples need to be contaned inside a batch. And it is crucial to pick negatives. But usually efforts are made to pick the proper negatives inside the batch, instead of in building the batches in a specific way.
This blogpost explaining how ranking losses work may be usefull https://gombru.github.io/2019/04/03/ranking_loss/